# Link to anchor on another page using URLSearchParams.get and javascript NOT using hash

Tags: javascript

I want make link to another page from mailing without using hash in link. I made simple code and i want to ask for advice. Is this example is ok?

```
var parametr = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
var link = parametr.get("utm_content");
console.log(link);

var location = window.location.href;
if (link == 'kat-power-audio') {
    function scrollTo(hash) {
        location.hash = "#power-audio";
    }
}
```

Comment: Assume we say yes, does it work? What advice are you looking for?

Comment: i'm struggle with this now, because page is reloading constantly. Don't know why

Comment: Consider updating the question to reflect that?

Comment: Ok, so after sometime i'm lost here, i don't know how can i link to anchor on page using java

Comment: May you explain the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: "actual problem" how link to anchor not using hash in link